# show there exists an integer k such that $2013^k$ ends with '0001'

Tags: combinatorics

Prove that there exists an integer k so that $2013^k$ ends with '0001'.

we couldn't figure this out.
i thought we might try to prove that we can find an integer m such that $m*10^4 +1 = 2013^k$, but was unable to get any clues.

both hints and similar solutions are welcome.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since you tagged combinatorics I thought about some Pidgeon hole principle proof, but I cannot figure out how to set it up

Comment: @YotamAlon: Should there be $0001$ and $10^4$ or $001$ and $10^3$ ?

Comment: you are right. fixed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose $S=\{2013^1,2013^2,2013^3,\cdots,2013^{10001}\}$

Then by Pigeonhole principle, there are at least two distinct elements of $S$ with same remainder modulo $10^4$, namely ,

$\exists i,j(i>j)$ s.t $2013^i\equiv2013^j \mod 10000$

$\Rightarrow 10000|2013^i-2013^j$

$\Rightarrow10000|2013^j(2013^{i-j}-1)$

Since $gcd(2013,10000)=1$, so $gcd(2013^j,10000)=1$. Thus we could conclude from the above:

$10000|2013^{i-j}-1$

Now the desired $k$ would be $i-j$, and there is $m$ such that:

$2013^{i-j}=10^4m+1.$

Comment: Looks good. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Since $gcd(2013,10^4)=1$, we will have $2013^{\varphi(10000)}\equiv1 \mod 10000$.

$\varphi(10000)=(5-1)(2-1)(5^3)(2^3)=4000$, so $10000|2013^{4000}-1$.

It leads us to there is a $m$ such that $2013^{4000}=10^4m+1$ ( the desired $k$ is $4000$ here)

Comment: The last four digits are meant, not three.

Comment: Thanks , I edited the solution.

Comment: I am not familiar with that $\varphi$ function. can you show a different proof?

Comment: I think I could came up with one more solution, check if it is correct ?

Answer (score 3):

Remember [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler's_theorem). Assume $k\ge 2$.

$(2013^k$ ends in $0001)\iff 2013^k\equiv 1\pmod{\! 10\, 000}$

Since $(2013,10\, 000)=1$, it is sufficient that $\varphi(10\, 000)\mid k\iff 4000\mid k$.

There exist infinitely many such integers $k$ ($k=4000m$ with $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ is sufficient).

It is also sufficient (and in fact necessary, so $\text{ord}_{10^4}(2013)=500$ (see [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Multiplicative_order) for what it denotes), but I won't prove it here) that $k=500m$ for some $m\in\Bbb Z^+$ because of [Carmichael's function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmichael_function), since $\lambda(10\, 000)=500$ and $(2013,10\, 000)=1$ (Carmichael's function is just a stronger version of Euler's theorem).

Answer (score 0):

You have to prove that for some $k$,
$$ 2013^{k}\equiv 1\pmod{10^4} $$
but since $2013=3\cdot 11\cdot 61$ and $10^4=2^4\cdot 5^4$, we have $\gcd(2013,10^4)=1$, so $2013$ is an element of the group $\mathbb{Z}_{/10^4\mathbb{Z}}^*$, and its order is a divisor of $\varphi(10000)=4000$ by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function#Euler.27s_theorem) and [Lagrange's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrange%27s_theorem_%28group_theory%29).

You may also prove that $k=\color{red}{500}$ works.